# Отказ выполнения команды запуска mysql в командной строке

Tags: веб-программирование, php, denwer, mysql

Освежаю свои знания по web - читая книгу Лауры Томсон "Разработка Web-приложений на PHP и MySQL" и пытаюсь на данный момент выполнить запуск mysql из командной строки (в университете нам показывали как это делать и получалось выполнить вышеуказанное действие). Запущен на данный момент Denwer. При попытке выполнить команду

```
mysql -h hostname -u username p
```

выдает результат указанный на скриншоте

[image]

Конечно я понимаю, что можно работать с базами данных MySQL и через браузер (запустив Denwer), но все же хочется добиться работоспособности и этой команды.

Answer (score 2):

Установите mysql. Если установлен, убедитесь что в переменной окружения PATH содержится путь к исполняемому файлу mysql, либо пишите полный путь к нему.

Comment: @Чад **как проверить установлен ли mysql (я могу лишь предположить, что установлен, поскольку он входит в denwer)** и **где находится исполняемый файл mysql**?

Comment: Поищите по паке денвера mysql*

Comment: @Чад Файл `mysql.exe` располагается в папке `C:\WebServers\usr\local\mysql-5.1\bin`. Я попытался прописать этот путь в `PATH` (путь включал также имя `mysql.exe`), но это ничего не дало и выходом стал переход в эту папку с помощью `cd` и запуск вышеуказанной команды из этой папки.

Comment: уберите имя mysql.exe

Answer (score 0):

Перейдите в директорию с установленным mysql помощью "cd"